# How to make nested Quick tab in a view?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I am using [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) for displaying the image gallery.

In views the FORMAT is Quicktab and the fields are ***Year ,Month ,Title and Images*** .

I have a gallery based on Year and month.I need to display the gallery based on year(main tab) under the year tab the month tab should be displayed.

e.g :
here under the year i need to display the months entered in the content type.Now in view's Quicktab format option i gave ***Grouping field Nr.1*** as **Year**.When i tried the ***Grouping field Nr.2*** to **Month**,the tab is not showing anything or the combination not working.

How can i show the nested tab in Quicktab or can you suggest any alternative ways?
[image: This is the layout .]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
 - create the view for the month (with the pictures) [field collection module can help you here]
 - Then you create the view for year and call the MonthView inside

(i know this is not the most advanced response you could get, but my knowledge is basic as i been using drupal since last month)

i hope this can help you.

Comment: there is VIEWS FIELD VIEW module too..